# How to connect DJI product using DJI mobile sdk

Tags: dji-sdk

I have been trying almost all samples in dji github (either android or ios) but couldn't connect my dji product (phantom 4 pro+ V2.0) to my app. I can successfully register my app by using my api key, but when I connect dji product to the phone with usb cable I cannot see any connection. Give me a help please.

Answer (score 1):

**For iOS App**: You need to add the external **UISupportedExternalAccessoryProtocols** keys to your plist file. Like this 
`

```
<key>UISupportedExternalAccessoryProtocols</key>
     <array>
         <string>com.dji.video</string>
         <string>com.dji.protocol</string>
         <string>com.dji.common</string>
     </array>
```

And then use the DJIAssistantSimulator to simulate to the drone location.

Answer (score 0):

The first step in connecting your drone to your application is by calling `DJISDKManager.registerApp` and pass an instance of `DJISDKManagerDelegate`.

```
class ProductPublisher : NSObject, ObservableObject {
    ...
    func registerWithSDK() {
        ...
        DJISDKManager.registerApp(with: self)
    }
    ...
}
```

The important part is your delegate implements some required methods and calling `DJISDKManager.startConnectionToProduct()`.

```
extension ProductPublisher : DJISDKManagerDelegate {
    func appRegisteredWithError(_ error: Error?) {
        // set breakpoint here
        DJISDKManager.startConnectionToProduct()
    }

    func productConnected(_ product: DJIBaseProduct?) {
        // set breakpoint here, this marks a successful connection
    }
}
```

The class `ProductPublisher` is a class of my own where I encapsulate all logic regarding registration and connection. It is part of a [tutorial series](https://twissmueller.medium.com/programming-dji-drones-97974c18af06) for iOS I am writing. What I have just explained is in part 2.